# HTML5 Audio , getting the sound of piano

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Im creating my html5 app for testing and Im working with audio api , for generating sound on keyboard I'm doing something like this

```
 keyboard.keyDown(function (note, frequency) {
                    var oscillator = context.createOscillator(),
                        gainNode = context.createGainNode();

                    oscillator.type = 2;
                    oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
                    gainNode.gain.value = 0.3;
                    oscillator.connect(gainNode);
                    if (typeof oscillator.noteOn !== 'undefined') {
                        oscillator.noteOn(0);
                    }
                    gainNode.connect(context.destination); 
                    nodes.push(oscillator);
                });
```

now my question is , cause I tryied to find examples on google but with no success ,what are the other parammetars that can be used for getting sound sounds like piano or some electronic instrument except oscillator and how to pass them ?

Comment: piano synthesis is quite a broad topic !!! only recently (less than 3 years) this synthesis has led to good results. Pianotech is one among them i tried with some joy, but the algorithm to have a good result are quite math hence cpu intensive. You might find tutorials on the net to get a basic piano, i.e. hammer sound + fundamental + harmonics + reverb + echo.

Comment: I'll be thankful if you have some source for tutorials to share ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are fairly new to synthesis. Before trying synthesis algorithms in code, I'd recommend playing with some of the software synthesizers that are available - VST or otherwise. This will give you a handle on the kind of parameters you want to be introducing into your algorithm. http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/allsynthsecrets.htm is an index for a series of really good synthesis tutorials. (Start at the bottom - part 1!)

Once you are ready to start experimenting in code, a great place to start would be to introduce an [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#ADSR_envelope) to change the volume or pitch of the sound over time (changing a parameter over time like this is called 'modulation'). This video may be of interest: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6pp6OMU5r8

Bear in mind that almost all acoustic instruments are difficult to convincingly synthesize algorithmically, and by far the easiest way to get close to a piano is to use samples of real piano notes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! :) One more question are there any basic thinks to start like changing LFO or combining more then one oscilators at once ?

Comment: There is an LFO code example here http://www.digitalsurgeons.com/blog/web-audiodata-javascript/ though have not tried it myself. http://digitalsurgeons.com/labs/dspad/ also shows how you can change frequency in realtime (with mouse) and has some mixed together waveforms - there's a link to a Github repo.

Comment: Also, for the sound on sound tutorials, this HTML5 modular synth could be useful: http://www.g200kg.com/en/docs/webmodular/

Comment: Sampling real piano notes would not work for microtones.

Comment: @MészárosLajos OP just talks about "sounds like piano" - no mention of microtones. However, if you want to simulate a microtonal piano, it would be sufficient for most purposes to just play a sampled note a little slow to deal with the range of microtones below it - easy to do with playbackRate in the Web Audio API.

Comment: I guess this is how most samplers work. If you want 40 notes of a piano, then there is around 10 original notes ditributed evenly, while the rest is just pitch shifted.

Comment: @MészárosLajos 10 notes would probably be seen as quite low quality - a 'good' sample set would probably have a note at least every 3 or 4 semitones (as well as a number of different velocity layers). But yes, the principle is the same.